# парсинг поисковой выдачи Bing

Tags: c#, парсер

Нужно спарсить ссылки из поисковой выдачи https://www.bing.com/
Делаю запрос с помощью библиотеки xNet на адрес https://www.bing.com/search?q=
В ответ приходит пустой документ. При просмотре html нашел "Не удалось найти ни одного результата для". В браузере по этому запросу все ищет. В чем может быть хитрость? При обращении к Гугл и Яндекс ищет нормально, а Bing не хочет. Кто- нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: [Краткое руководство. Использование пакета SDK Поиска в Интернете Bing для C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/web-search-sdk-quickstart)

Comment: Очень вам советую отказаться от `xNet`. Как минимум по той простой причине, что его автор забросил, а это значит, что он уже не поддерживает много современных протоколов (tls например) (мне например пришлось переписывать xNet для своего древнего проекта и до сих пор жалею, что послушал знакомого, который мне его предложил). По поводу вопроса, опять же, простой `WebClient` спокойно [получает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dRfC.png) все необходимые данные.

Comment: Для использования SDK нужна учетка Azure, а её не получить. По поводу xNet, спасибо, попробую без нее.

Comment: Попробовал с WebClient - то же самое. Документ то он присылает но без результатов. Вы вставьте присланное в html файл и откройте браузером - там пусто. А в самом документе можно найти строку "Не удалось найти ни одного результата для"

Comment: Нашли решение проблемы? в чем там дело?